# Rasterise polygon layer using QGIS 3.0.3

Tags: qgis-3, rasterization

I am trying to rasterise a simple polygon layer [this file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d7j5hoXrrOPYjWLb8bJxqy6fehBhG1pO) using QGIS but cannot get a sensible output.

The [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster) doesn't appear to have been updated for version 3 yet, and does not match.

The options I have are
[image: rasterise options].

What options I be using to rasterise the polygon layer by attribute LandID?

(I got the result I expected swapping to 2.8 - but I'd like to figure out how to do this with the new version)

Comment: There should something in the dropdown for 'Field to use for a burn-in value' but you will need to specify a width/height for your raster before running. What field type is 'LandID'? String fields would not be provided as an option.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson -  LandID is an integer value.  The answer below worked for me - the error I was making was using an extent smaller than the original polygon rather than clipping after rasterising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select the field you want to use `LandID`. Also you need to select the desired Width/Horizontal resolution and Hight/Vertical resolution and the extent to be same as the polygon layer as in the following image:

[image]

Under Use Layer/Canvas extent, select ExamplePolygon.

Here is the output:

[image]

I used `QGIS 3.2`.